# Process stalls when launched in .NET (ffmpeg)

Tags: c#, .net, process, ffmpeg

I'm trying to launch `ffmpeg` as a Process in .NET (C#), but in some cases, depending on the arguments (specifically, if I omit video arguments in order to create an audio file), it's stalling. It launches, outputs some lines, but then just stalls (using 0% CPU). When the parent .NET process is killed, it continues, and if I let it continue, `ffmpeg` produces the file correctly. I thought it might be due to using `Peek()` to look at the stream, so I just simplified it to the following, which behaves the same:

```
_process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        FileName = "c:\\ffmpeg.exe",
        Arguments = string.Format(
    "-i {0} {1} {2} {3} -y {4}", inputPath, videoArgs, audioArgs, options, outputPath)
    }
};
_process.Start();
_process.WaitForExit();
```

`ffmpeg` gets to the point where it outputs information about the input video/audio streams before stalling. Executing the command via the command prompt works as expected.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

**Edit:**

Just to add, I tried `UseShellExecute = true` (and `RedirectStandardError = false`), and this works. I still need to read the output, however, so this doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 7):

Have a read of this 
[MSDN on RedirectStandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx)

Apparently this is a bit fiddly and can deadlock if the output or error stream buffers get filled up. Sit's there waiting for you to read what it's wrote...

Comment: [Answers that consist mainly of a link are not good answers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: You're right, if I put _process.StandardError.ReadToEnd() before the WaitForExit() call, it works. However, the problem still exists when I use _process.StandardError.Peek(). Is there any way around this?

Comment: @RhysCausey `.Peek` dies not empty the stream, just returns the next character in the stream and doesn't remove it. - so if the buffer is filling up, you'll have to `.Read*()` it to empty it.

Comment: Only two ettiquette failures in one day. I'm doing well, normally I can irritate hundreds of people before breakfast.

Comment: I was only able to get it to not hang by removing standarderror redirecting. I already had WaitForExit() at the end, but it still hung, disabling the error output worked. Though it is a bit inconvenient if an error occurs...

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758899/ffmpeg-from-a-c-sharp-app-using-process-class-user-prompt-not-shown-in-standar), in some cases FFmpeg manipulates the screen memory directly *without using the standard output and error streams*. One example of this is the `[file] already exists. Overwrite? [y/N]` prompt.

I'm guessing you've run the program outside if .NET to see what the output is? If it is a prompt like the one above then it might pay to avoid the trouble and attempt to provide an argument that will skip it eg. the `-y` command that forces FFmpeg to overwrite a file.