# ffmpeg from a C# app using Process class - user prompt not shown in standardError

Tags: c#, process, ffmpeg, redirectstandardoutput

I am writing an app to run ffmpeg using c#.  My program redirects the standardError output to a stream so it can be parsed for progress information.

During testing I have found a problem:

If the output is shown in a command window rather than being redirected ffmpeg will display it's normal headers followed by *"file c:\temp\testfile.mpg  already exists.  overwrite [y]"*.  If I click on the command window and press y the program continues to encode the file.

If the StandardError is redirected to my handler and then printed to the console, I see the same header information that was displayed in the command window now printed to the console. **except for the file...already exists prompt**.  If I click in the command window and press y the program continues to process the file.

Is there a stream other than standardOutput or standardError that is used when the operator is prompted for information, or am I missing something else?

```
public void EncodeVideoWithProgress(string filename, string arguments, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        Process proc = new Process();

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + " \"" + filename + "\" " + arguments;

        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; //set to true for testing

        proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(NetErrorDataHandler);

        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();


        StreamReader reader = proc.StandardOutput;
         string line;
         while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        { Console.WriteLine(line); }
     proc.WaitForExit();
}

private static void NetErrorDataHandler(object sendingProcess,
               DataReceivedEventArgs errLine)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errLine.Data))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(errLine.Data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than going through all this stuff,  use the "-y" command line option when you start the process, which will force ffmpeg to overwrite existing files.

Comment: Thanks for the work-around.  I will use it.  I am however still curious why information shows on the command window but not on the standardError or standardOutput streams.

Comment: That is tied to some old hooks into DOS.  The program is manipulating screen memory directly without using the standard output and error streams.

Comment: Windows still supports this alternative approach

Comment: Thanks, accepted the answer.  I'll probably use the -n option which does send a message via standardError 'File... already exists.  Exiting'

Comment: Ahh of course. Thanks for this workaround, that's really helpful. So is there any way to retrieve this output at all?